# Trying to make a simple img gallery- my arrow isn't working properly. Please help.

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a gallery of images, one page to the next like on this site:

francescoclemente.net/now/1.html

I downloaded some arrow.png images to make the arrow, and implemented them into my HTML like so:

```
<div class="paintings">

<img src="stanpics/paintings/nyc/bathesda fountain'.jpg" alt="bathesda fountain"        title="bathesda fountain">
<p class="pdescribe">bathesda fountain</p>

</div>

<div class="rightarrow">
<a href="paintingsnyc2.html"><img src="rightarrow.png" class="rightarrow" title="next"     alt="next"></a>

 </div>

<div class="leftarrow">

<a href="paintingsnyc.html"><img src="leftarrow.png" class="rightarrow" title="back"  alt="back"></a>

</div>
```

The div "paintings" is the art image. The 'leftarrow' and 'right arrow' are the two arrows I want to put on the side. For some reason, the pointer icon (indicating an anchor tag or link) for the mouse will not show up unless you mouse over below the right arrow image. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Here is the CSS for the arrow classes.

```
.leftarrow {

margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
bottom: 82px;
left: 120px;
 }




 .rightarrow {

  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 190px;

  }
```

I've tried everything I could think of, I know it's probably something very simple messing me up here. Your corrections are appreciated.

Comment: Which browser is causing trouble for you? I checked with Chrome, FF and IE9 - all good.

Comment: using Safari, I haven't checked the others actually... Maybe it's a safari thing?

Comment: Checked on Safari (Win) - good too. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to reproduce your issue without the images, but here are a few ideas you could try:

- add a `height` and `width` to the css for your buttons
- add a `display:block` to the css for your buttons

Answer (score 1):

The w3c.org validator gives a few errors regarding arrows. Maybe fixing them will fix your problem.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=francescoclemente.net%2Fnow%2F1.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=francescoclemente.net%2Fnow%2F1.html&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=nl